# Why doesn't this for-loop let me input text the first cycle?

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

What I want to do is ask the user for a number of strings to read into an array, and then ask the user to input that number of strings and read them into the array. When I run this code it never asks me for an input the first cycle of the first for-loop, just prints out "String #0: String #1: " and then I can input text. Why is that and what did I do wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ovn9 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Number of inputs: ");

    int lines= sc.nextInt();
    String[] text=new String[lines];

    for(int x=0; x<text.length; x++)
    {
        System.out.print("String #"+x+": ");
        text[x] = sc.nextLine();
    }

    for(int y=0; y<text.length; y++)
        System.out.println(text[y]);

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buffering.

`nextInt()` does not consume the newline in the input buffer that was put there when you entered the number of inputs. In the iteration 0 of the for loop, there's already a line of input in the buffer and `nextLine()` can complete immediately and the program will wait for new input line only in iteration 1. To ignore the newline in the input, you can add just another `nextLine()` call before entering the for loop.

Comment: Thank you, that worked wonders. I think I understand what you mean although I'm not familiar with the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change your loop to use 'sc.next()'

```
for ( int x = 0; x < lines; x++ ) {
    System.out.print("String #" + x + ": ");
    text[x] = sc.next();
}
```

It can be explained by the Java API

String next(): Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

String nextLine(): Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.