# scan.nextLine does not work

Tags: java

I used Java and I tried to write program that reads a number of patients and then let the employee enter their names and ages.

and I want the program reads full name such as (Maha Saeed) so I wrote the code like this but I don't know why it does not work

```
name = scan.nextLine();
```

and this is the full code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Answer1
{
static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
public static void main (String[] args)
{

int age ; 
int PatientNumber ;
int PatientNO;
String name ;


System.out.print("Enter number of patients :");

PatientNumber =  scan.nextInt();
PatientNO = 1;

while ( PatientNO <= PatientNumber)
{
System.out.println("Patient #" +PatientNO);
System.out.print("Enter patient's Name: ");
name = scan.nextLine(); //<- here is the problem if I write scan.next it works but it reads only the first name

System.out.print("Enter patient's Age: ");
age= scan.nextInt();
PatientNO = PatientNO + 1;
}

}
}
```

thanks all

Comment: "Does not work" is not a useful problem description. Doesn't work **how**? What happens instead of what you want? Where do you see in the documentation that it should do something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [Why can't I enter a string in Scanner(System.in), when calling nextLine()-method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265216/why-cant-i-enter-a-string-in-scannersystem-in-when-calling-nextline-method) and [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint)

Simple solution, you can consume the \n character:

```
scan.nextLine();
name = scan.nextLine();
```