# Need help debugging my Java code. While loop is not executing a function on the first run through

Tags: java, while-loop, computer-science

Im in AP computer science as a high school student. I was bored so i decided to write a rock paper scissor code. It runs a while loop to play a few games in a row and determine a winner, but the first run on the while loop doesnt take in the user input. Its as if the user = scan.nextLine doesnt work on the first run

```
  Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
  String answer = "none";
  System.out.println("How many games of Rock, Paper, Scissors would you like to play?");
  int games = scan.nextInt();
  int count = 0;
  int computerWins = 0;
  int userWins = 0;
  int computer = 0;
  String user = " ";
  while (count < 10)
  {
    System.out.println("Enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors");
    user = scan.nextLine();
    computer = ((int)(Math.round((Math.random () * 2) + 1)));
    if (computer == 1)
    {
      answer = "Rock";
    }
    else if (computer == 2)
    {
      answer = "Paper";
    }
    else if (computer == 3)
    {
      answer = "Scissors";
    }
  System.out.println("The Computer Chose: " + answer);
   if ((answer.equals("Rock")) && (user.equals("Scissors")))
   {
     System.out.println("The Computer's Rock beats your Scissors");
     computerWins++;
   }
   else if ((answer.equals("Paper")) && (user.equals("Rock")))
   {
     System.out.println("The Computer's Paper beats your Rock");
     computerWins++;
   }
   else if ((answer.equals("Scissors")) && (user.equals("Paper")))
   {
     System.out.println("The Computer's Scissors beat your Paper");
     computerWins++;
   }
   else if (answer.equals(user))
     System.out.println("TIE! Your " + user + " is the same as the Computer's " + answer);
   else
   {
     System.out.println("Your " + user + " beats the Computer's " + answer);
     userWins++;
   }
   count++;
   System.out.println("Score Stands: Computer " + computerWins + " You " + userWins);
  }
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. Which one are you trying to write?

Comment: I don't understand why JavaScript was tagged. Is this not "Java"?

Comment: Java, my bad. Anyways, Im running code through the compiler "Dr. Java" and that first input isn't working.The code works if i block out the code that says "int games = scan.nextInt ();" but i dont know why

Comment: This is Java, could you edit the title please?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you might find you're using Java.

In terms of your question, this comes up frequently on Stackoverflow (eg. [Why can't I enter a string in Scanner(System.in), when calling nextLine()-method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265216/why-cant-i-enter-a-string-in-scannersystem-in-when-calling-nextline-method), or practically an exact copy of your problem, [Why doesn't this for-loop let me input text the first cycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815396/why-doesnt-this-for-loop-let-me-input-text-the-first-cycle)). As a high school student, I'm a little surprised you haven't been taught to research what you can before calling on others.

Anyway ... if you use `nextInt` the scanner will not move to the next line, so when you use `nextLine` you are actually reading to the end of the same line as your integer.

There are several ways of dealing with this but, for simplicity, you could just use a `scan.nextLine` statement after you have acquired the integer. So that part of your code would look like this:

```
System.out.println("How many games of Rock, Paper, Scissors would you like to play?");
int games = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thanks. I did attempt to find something but I'm not skilled enough in computer science to have a succinct search criteria, so I couldn't find anything that actually helped me. Could you go more in depth, or simplify your explanation of why this happens?

Comment: @SeanTheSaxMan, I think you're missing my point. That's for you to research. If you can find this site and pose a question here, then you can certainly do a google search. I wonder if this is the cause of the boredom you proclaim.

Answer (score 0):

```
int games = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
```

Just add this portion of code after your `nextInt()` call to consume the rest of the line.

If this is not done,

```
user = scan.nextLine();
```

at this line, user will take the value of the rest of the line where the `int` was.